# Simple Localhost Server in Xcode/Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, localhost, host

I am making a macos app in XCode, and I was wondering if there was a way to make it host a local server that is visible across the network.

I am trying to find a way so that it would host something on the devices's network with it's hostname/ip address, so if someone goes to `http://hostname:5000` they would be able to see the response, and the app would be able to see the request, just like how hosting a local python server works. Is there any way to do this in XCode with Swift?

For example: the user presses 'start server' on their screen. The server is hosted across the network. Anytime a request is made to it, they get a notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make you concern you may find some sample codes, including local web server inside the app.Few of them  I found are:

https://github.com/ooper-shlab/MyWebViewApp-Swift

https://github.com/depoon/SwiftLocalhost

The main thing is it's just a public
, experimental code, so it's not simple, not easy to adopt, not all coding best-recommended, far from readable and may have severe bugs.But you can use it as a working example and take any parts of it into your app.